# MSAL returned bad token from iOS Swift sample

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am attempting to authenticate a user using Azure B2C in an iOS app.  I am following the sample that's available here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal

I can acquire the token but when I try to call a protected web service I get a 401 error.  When I use PostMan and acquire a token and then copy it into the application it works correctly.

It appears that the Urls being used to get the tokens are different - this one works in PostMan:
https://{orgname}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={policy}

This url appears to be the default set in MSAL in the iOS example:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/{policy}

I tried updating the kAuthority variable to be the Url that works in PostMan but that results in an error:

▿ Optional
  - some : Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-42002 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Authority validation is not supported for this type of authority}

Does anyone know the proper configuration for the MSAL library for the new b2clogin.com urls?

Comment: You need to disable authority validation AFAIK if you use b2clogin.com

Comment: That worked.  I set validateAuthority=false

Comment: Can you help with a snippet to set the validateAuthority=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#set-the-validateauthority-property

> If you're using MSAL, set the ValidateAuthority property to false. When ValidateAuthority is set to false, redirects are allowed to b2clogin.com.

So you need to disable authority validation to use the b2clogin.com URLs.

Comment: how to disable ValidateAuthority set to false? is it in code or account